# Remove event listener in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have following code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('drag')[i].addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    console.log('mousedown' + i);
});
```

It would be easy, if I would be able to name the function inside listener. But it's not possible in my case.

It would look like:

```
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, nameFunction);
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: There is absolutely *no way* in which you could store a reference to that function separately…?! `let cb = (e) => { ... }; ...addEventListener(..., cb); removeEventListener(..., cb);`?

Comment: Why can't you name the function?

Comment: @deceze Looking forward for full reply.

Comment: @itamar because it's an arrow function. But saving it's reference into a variable is easy enough, as deceze has shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can write like this.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('drag')[i].addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFun);
function mouseDownFun(e){
  console.log('mousedown' + i);
}
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, mouseDownFun);
```

So whenever mouse down event will be triggered it will listen in mouseDownFun.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two ways**

1. When you define a function, then add and remove the listener when you want:

   ```
   // Define a function
   const handler = () => {
       console.log('Click event...');
   }

   // Select the element and add event listener
   const img = document.querySelector('img');
       img.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

   // ...

   // Remove the event listener
   img.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);
   ```
2. When you add an event listener and remove it on event:

   ```
   // Select the element and add event listener
   const img = document.querySelector('img');
      img.addEventListener('click', function handler(event) {
         console.log('Click event...');

         // On event, remove the event listener
         event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, handler);
      });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> It would be easy, if I would be able to name the function inside listener. But it's not possible in my case.

Don't use an arrow function if it doesn't allow you to do what you want.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('drag')[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function handler(e) {
    console.log('mousedown' + i);
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
});
```

Comment: Can he name the fat arrow function, and use the name that way?

Comment: Only by assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @prosti *"fat"* suggests there's varieties of arrow functions, but really there is only one kind; just say "arrow function"

Comment: @naomik, the future time script kiddies at 39 may bring something like this soon `->` into the ES world, and then my comment will not be precise any more.

Comment: @prosti funny, but I think you're better off calling it by its actual name now. If there is a new syntax in the future, I'm sure it will come with its own name.

Comment: @naomik, yes I think that I first time heard for the fat arrow in one of the dan abramov free lessons on egghead, but I will follow your tip from now on.